# strapi not starting - strapi 3.0.0 stable - Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL 143.204.0.57:1337

Tags: node.js, strapi, nodejs-server

Recently i upgraded to strapi stable version 3.0.0 from beta 20.

when i run strapi in my local its working fine but when i try to run in docker i am getting this error

```
(node:16) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-01-03T09:49:01.824Z] error Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL 143.204.0.57:1337
    at listenOnMasterHandle (net.js:1398:18)
    at rr (internal/cluster/child.js:138:12)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/child.js:105:7)
    at process.onInternalMessage (internal/cluster/utils.js:48:5)
    at process.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:912:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

my config/server.js file contents is

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
    //socket: '/tmp/nginx.socket', // only use if absolutely required
    emitErrors: false,
    url: env('PUBLIC_URL', 'https://example.com/api/v1'),
    //proxy: env.bool('IS_PROXIED', true),
    /*
    cron: {
        enabled: env.bool('CRON_ENABLED', false),
    },
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was environment variables predefinided in my system, specificly `HOST` and `PORT`. So i modified `env` (in ubuntu you can type `env` in terminal and shows you environment variables defined in your system), and for do that i went to the path `/etc/environment` and delete variables `HOST` and `PORT`, with an editor (example: `sudo nano /etc/environment`) and i restarted the computer, for the update of environment variables.